# Gmail API autologin in swift

Tags: ios, swift, gmail-api, autologin

I'm using this example
[Gmail Api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios?ver=swift)

I tried to find a proper method of the api to do this and it has not been possible.

It occurred to me to save credentials in NSUserDefaults and add them to service.authorizer manually.

This works, but in about an hour I answered: `The operation Could not be completed. (Invalid Credentials)`.

I wonder if there is a function to refresh these credentials.

Comment: Do you mean refreshing access token? please explain your scenario clearly.

Comment: Did you check this link https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline ? You can use offline access in your oauth code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find the solution.

I'm mantain the NSUserDefault Functionality

```
curl -d "client_id=yourClientId&client_secret=yourClientSecret&refresh_token=yourRefreshToken&grant_type=refresh_token" https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
```

The Response is something like this:

```
{
 "access_token": "ya29.KALxxxxyvE5PI3-s6oBAP74uGFE8rOhho5XYfvExfU3lxHdX23HWbKlkR4YI1xxxx",
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "expires_in": 3600,
 "id_token": "xjc4ZDg3NWY5MDA5YzMzZjFlODljOGExMDFjM2UwNDMyNWQ2YmQ0MTEifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwiYXRfaGFzaCI6InRJWVE0b2pBZfNyRlJXdFEiLCJhdWQiOiIyMDM3MjIwMDA2NzMtdGIwamF1OWhwamFsa21yaHFxcDkybnBxamo2ZjhkcWcuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVx1ODM5MTE5MDk0OTAzMjg3NjAiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXpwIjoiMjAzNzIyMDAwNjczLXRiMGphdTlocGphbGttcmhxcXA5Mm5wcWpqNmY4ZHFnLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiaGQiOiJ2b3ZdwiZW1haWwiOiJqZ29uemFsZXpAdm92c29sdXRpb25zLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTQ0NzE2OTU5NSwiZXhwIjoxNDQ3MTczMTk1fQ.gZiYdgEPhYkQTvjgxugaMaXTIH3652_E_3h_khHgaKFA56ko3VqBF9qlzJ-1LDIoTO8G2eQWa6ncE7aEwLvxelZ8429iJUCIH-1cmeuck_LWpFIdQ9sQN8u4I7ABTRWPpZ3vL8nXMNmPGynvCDWimffYCGWeVZGs3uv0O7pFftqIKMJchVk_WyC5fm9i8m-cGPN-UcrvgZKrFEOMydvF83HQzIR-x28nB1evbMV6WN8guBdZ6pVAr_2agyzoNuSO5tkV_O-790IRmU432Omv2nHBD3QQKEqv6aHe3i_F3ioPREuWduYY3yjlg0QYyh-nrzAXyzF3wbg"
}
```

i replace the `access_token` saved in userDefault with `access_token` from response.

Replace Values in GTLServiceGmail `service.authorizer`

More information [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#refreshtoken)

Comment: Do you have a full swift code sample where this works. I think the gmail documentation is not up to date and apart from that there is no Swift code sample. The authorization part is essential to authenticate your app to make any GMail API calls